# Laravel - Get users with their roles name

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to get my users with their roles (to list, not to check!) on standard Auth system.
I do somethink like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join( 'user_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_roles.user_id' )
            ->select('id', 'first_name', 'role_id')
            ->get();
```

And I getting this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#552 ▼
    +"id": 9670
    +"first_name": "Paweł"
    +"role_id": 1337
  }
  1 => {#553 ▼
    +"id": 9670
    +"first_name": "Paweł"
    +"role_id": 100
  }
]
```

But I need this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#552 ▼
    +"id": 9670
    +"first_name": "Paweł"
    +"roles": 'Admin, AnotherRole'
  }
]
```

How can I do this?
Structures of my tables:
**users**
'id'
'firstname'
... etc.
**roles**
'id'
'name'
**user_roles**
'user_id'
'role_id'

Answer (score 2):

in your user class add this:

```
   public function roles()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
   }
```

now you can do

```
$user->roles
```

to access the roles.

documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

Try This code

App/User

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Controller

```
  use App/User;

  public funtion getUsers(User $user)  {
    $getUsersWithRole =  $user->with('roles')->get();
    dd($getUsersWithRole);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

User Model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Controller:

```
 use App/User;

  public funtion index(User $user)  {
    $users=  User::with('roles')->get();    
  }
```